# Recreate a git repository from a server stored .git directory

Tags: git

So I messed up a box hosting gitlab, and the only thing I was able to salvage was a directory full of directories named 'project-name.git'. The contents of which look like this:

```
hooks.old.1474886538
info
objects
refs
config
description
HEAD
hooks
packed-refs
```

Just copying this directory to a new gitlab installation doesn't work, of course because there is also the whole database that it maintains which I have now lost.

All my repos are there, all the data is there (I've lost issues/todos/milestones, but I guess I can live with that). Is there a way to get a repo out of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. What you have is a bare git repository.  Just stick it in a directory somewhere, and then:

```
git clone /path/to/bare/repository myrepository
```

This will check it out into a directory named `myrepository`.